# Calling into python code using Pythonnet from C# and custom C# classes

Tags: c#, python, .net, dictionary, python.net

I have the majority of my code base in c# where data is entered into a datagrid in a GUI and then this is taken into a set of python3 functions to interrogate the data further.
From the datagrid information , user defined objects containing boolean, float and dictionary properties are populated which are then passed into python.

Currently the python code is using only python functionality and I think this may be the issue as the dict.keys() method in the python funciton is not recognising the C# dictionary that is passed in.

Is there an easy way to convvert the c# dictionary into a python dictionary so that the python code can be unchanged?

Thanks!

Comment: A dynamic converter was published by @yagweb for dictionaries, lists and even more complex types. Please see examples on github: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/623

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty work around would be to use [NewtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) nugget to serialize your class contents (in this case, your dictionary) and convert it into a `JSON`.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
myDictionary.Add("key1","value1");
myDictionary.Add("key2","value2");

//Now convert the dictionary into json.
var jsonToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDictionary);
```

Now pass in that `jsonToSend` to the python code and at the python code, load the json into a `dict` using `json` module like below:

```
import json
passedin_json = 'the output of your method that receives the json'
loaded_json_data = json.loads(passedin_json)
```

And done, Now you've successfully transferred your `C#` dictionary to your `python` dict